# Replacing multiple value names in a panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column `colA` that has multiple values in a pandas dataframe. I want every value that starts with `spare1` in this column to be replaced with the words `email_petition`. e.g. `spare1signed`, `spare1not` signed yet' etc. will all be converted to just `email_petition`.

I am using the following code:

```
petition = df.colA.str.startswith('spare1')

if df.colA == petition:
    df.colA.replace(petition, 'email_petition', inplace=True)
```

but I get the following error:
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use `a.empty`, `a.bool()`, `a.item()`, `a.any()` or `a.all()`.

I also tried the following code which doesn't give me an error but doesn't seem to work as the values don't change:

```
petition = df.colA.str.startswith('spare1')

if df.colA is petition:
    df.colA.replace(petition, 'email_petition', inplace=True)
```

would love some advice on this!

thanks

Comment: Does my answer helped you ?

Comment: @.. user8322222    [what i should do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)  must learn!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.colA.replace({'spare1':'email_petition'}, regex=True)
```

For complete removal:

```
df['colA'].replace({'spare1signed':'email_petition','spare1notsigned':'email_petition'})
```

Answer (score 0):

When possible always vectorize your operations on a dataframe. In your case the `for` loop is not required, you can simply apply a function to the whole column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'colA':['spare1signed','spare1not signed','no action']})
df.colA = df.colA.apply(lambda x: 'email_sent' if 'spare1' in x else x)
df

>>
    colA
0   email_sent
1   email_sent
2   no action
```

Here we assign the column with a lambda function that replaces any value in the column if `spare1` is found with `email_sent`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be simplified with `replace` using regex pattern:

Borrowed the data from @BernardL

**Example DataFrame** with column name `colA` :

```
>>> df
               colA
0      spare1signed
1  spare1not signed
2         no action
```

Applying regex method which says whatever ends with `signed$` Just replace them to `email_sent` :

**Result:**

```
>>> df['colA'] = df.colA.replace(r'.*signed$', 'email_sent', regex=True)
>>> df
         colA
0  email_sent
1  email_sent
2   no action
```

**Regex Meaning:**

> `.*` matches any character (except for line terminators)
>
> `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many
>   times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>
> `signed` matches the characters signed literally (case sensitive)
>
> `$` asserts position at the end of a line